# In linux, why do I lose UDP packets if I call send() as fast as possible?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, udp

The implicit question is: If Linux blocks the `send()` call when the socket's send buffer is full, why should there be any lost packets?

More details:
I wrote a little utility in C to send UDP packets as fast as possible to a unicast address and port. I send a UDP payload of 1450 bytes each time, and the first bytes are a counter which increments by 1 for every packet. I run it on a Fedora 20 inside VirtualBox on a desktop PC with a 1Gb nic (=quite slow).

Then I wrote a little utility to read UDP packets from a given port which checks the packet's counter against its own counter and prints a message if they are different (i.e. 1 or more packets have been lost). I run it on a Fedora 20 bi-xeon server with a 1Gb ethernet nic (=super fast). It does show many lost packets.

Both machines are on a local network. I don't know exactly the number of hops between them, but I don't think there are more than 2 routers between them.

Things I tried:

- Add a delay after each `send()`. If I set a delay of 1ms, then no packets are lost any more. A delay of 100us will start losing packets.
- Increase the receiving socket buffer size to 4MiB using `setsockopt()`. That does not make any difference...

Please enlighten me!

Comment: I don't think this is really a programming question. It's a bit murky, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For UDP the `SO_SNDBUF` socket option only limits the size of the datagram you can send. There is no explicit throttling send socket buffer as with TCP. There is, of course, in-kernel queuing of frames to the network card.

In other words, [`send(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html) might drop your datagram without returning an error (check out description of `ENOBUFS` at the bottom of the manual page).

Then the packet might be dropped pretty much anywhere on the path:

- sending network card does not have free hardware resources to service the request, frame is discarded,
- intermediate routing device has no available buffer space or implements some congestion avoidance algorithm, drops the packet,
- receiving network card cannot accept ethernet frames at given rate, some frames are just ignored.
- reader application does not have enough socket receive buffer space to accommodate traffic spikes, kernel drops datagrams.

From what you said though, it sounds very probable that the VM is not able to send the packets at a high rate. Sniff the wire with `tcpdump(1)` or `wireshark(1)` as close to the source as possible, and check your sequence numbers - that would tell you if it's the sender that is to blame.

Comment: Thanks Nikolai. The man page indeed states "Packets are just silently dropped when a device queue overflows". That's very likely what is happening there. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 2):

Even if `send()` blocks when the send buffer is full (provided that you didn't set `SOCK_NONBLOCK` on the socket to put it in non-blocking mode) the receiver must still be fast enough to handle all incoming packets. If the receiver or any intermediate system is slower than the sender, packets will get lost when using UDP. Note that *slower* does not only apply to the speed of the network interface but to the whole network stack plus the userspace application.

In your case it is quite possible that the receiver is receiving all packets but can't handle them fast enough in userpace. You can check that by recording and analyzing your traffic via `tcpdump` or `wireshark`.

If you don't want to loose packets then switch to TCP.

Answer (score 0):

- Any of the two routers you mentionned might drop packets if there is an overload,
- and the receiving PC might drop or miss packets as well under certain circumstances such as overload.

Answer (score 0):

As one of the above posters said, UDP is a simple datagram protocol that does not guarantee delivery. Either because of local machine, equipments on the network,etc. That is the reason why many current developers will recommend, if you want reliability, to switch to TCP. However, if you really want to stick to the UDP protocol and there are many valid reasons to do that, you will need to find a library that will help you guarantee the delivery. Look for SS7 projects especially in telephony APIs where UDP is used to transmit voice,data and signalling information. For your sole purpose app may i suggest the enet UDP library.http://enet.bespin.org/